# Production Django Application Throwing/Not Throwing 500 Error based on Debug = Value

Tags: django, http, nginx, gunicorn

I have an production django application that runs fine with `Debug = True;` but doesn't with `Debug=False`.

If I load run the domain, it shows my `urls.py` file, which is really bad.

I want to get my application where it uses `Debug=False` and `TEMPLATE_DEBUG=False` instead of `Debug=True` and `TEMPLATE_DEBUG=True` , since by using the `True` value it exposes the application

If I view my **error.log** under nginx with `DEBUG=True`:

```
2013/10/25 11:35:34 [error] 2263#0: *5 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: xx.xxx.xx.xxx, server: *.myapp.com, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:8001/", host: "www.myapp.com"
```

view my **access.log** under nginx with `DEBUG=True`:

```
xx.xxx.xx.xxx - - [25/Oct/2013:11:35:33 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 502 173 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.8; rv:24.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/24.0"
```

So my question is, why when I set `DEBUG=True` and `TEMPLATE_DEBUG=True` does it load successfully showing the application and when I set `DEBUG=False` and `TEMPLATE_DEBUG=False` it shows the custom http 500 error page? (I have created to handle http 500 errors)

Comment: To be clear: is it working fine with DEBUG=True and not with False?

Comment: Yes it is. Does that make sense?

Comment: What is in gunicorn.log?

Comment: Its blank with nothing in it

Comment: did you set your allowed_hosts in your settings?

Comment: What if you set loglevel=debug for gunicorn and check the log?

Comment: So, this is so weird, but somehow this is now working with Debug=False. @DmitryDemidenko and toad013 - appreciate your help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to **Toad013** and **Dmitry** for their suggestions.

It appears the issue might have been with how nginx and gunicorn were being started and not a configuration issue, thus, I ended up using the following to start my app:

```
/usr/local/bin/gunicorn -c /home/ubuntu/virtualenv/gunicorn_config.py myapp.wsgi
sudo nginx -c /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
```